# How to use log4j extras 1.2.17

Tags: java, log4j

I want to change from using a file size based RollingFileAppender to a DailyRollingFileAppender with log4j 1.2.17, but the docs say that there are known synchronisation issues with that appender, and that the appender from the log4j extras package should be used instead (I'm aware that log4j 2 is available and doesn't have any known issues in relation to this).

When I replace the regular log4j-1.2.17 jar with log4j-extras-1.2.17 that I [downloaded from the Apache site](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/download.html), I get a ClassNotFoundException on `org.apache.log4j.or.RendererMap`. I can see that it does exist in the regular package, but not in extras. I know that the regular package is marked as a dependency of the extras package, but the extras download on Apache site (and Maven Central) appears to be a bundle. If I was to include the regular log4j package as well, what's to stop the class loader from using the broken appender class from the regular package instead of from extras?

How do I use this library?

I have since upgraded to the 2.x API because it was possible for me to use the compatibility bridge. I would still be interested to know why this wouldn't work. Was it fundamentally broken or was I missing something?

Comment: You shouldn't replace log4j with log4j-extras, but use them both together.

Comment: But there's conflicting classes, specifically `org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender`. How is the class loader to know it should use the extras version? Where can I get a non-bundled version of the extras package? Are you saying that if I include both in my project, the extras lib will compliment the core package and just work?

Comment: Oh wow, that's is very poor design. You'll especially get into this issue when you add this as a Maven or Gradle dependency, because log4j extras has a dependency on log4. That means that adding log4j extras as a dependency automatically adds log4 as dependency. If the two classes are different, that's just asking for problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already noticed [`apache-log4j-extras`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/apache-log4j-extras/1.2.17) is an OSGI bundle created by the [`maven-bundle-plugin`](https://felix.apache.org/documentation/_attachments/components/bundle-plugin/index.html).

Since a single Java package can be provided by only one OSGI bundle, the `apache-log4j-extras` contains copies of all `log4j` classes from the packages shared between the two projects. This does **not** mean that you can deploy `apache-log4j-extras` without `log4j`: `apache-log4j-extras` does not contain the packages that are specific to `log4j`, like `org.apache.log4j.or`.

Even if the two artifacts share classes, this does not constitute a problem: the shared classes are identical. It is only a problem if you use mismatching versions of `log4j` and `apache-log4j-extras`.

**Remark**: the "broken" class `org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender` from `log4j` you are probably referring to, has a different fully qualified class name from the one provided by `apache-log4j-extras` (`org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender`, notice the `rolling` part in the name).